# xcode and storyboard: how build an user profile view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

how can i build an user profile view like this (Periscope but is similar to many other apps).

It's a tableviewcontroller? If it is, how can i put the image of the user with background (it's in the first cell or above the tableview?)

[image]

Comment: This is called "Sticky headers". The CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout library handles it perfectly.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

The only thing is that it uses collection view instead of the table view.

Answer (score 2):

I'd build it this way:

`UIViewController` with `UITableView` + custom `UIView` on top.

If you want to use already implemented libraries, check this out :

- [MGSpotyViewController](https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGSpotyViewController)
- [jcbannerView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jcbannerview)
- [Facade](https://github.com/mamaral/Facade)

They have pretty similar logic that's described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a custom tableviewcontroller. Everything is a cell but it is hard to create only using storyboard. you create a dynamic table view and ad 3 prototype cell for it (1: Blue cell, 2:Grey empty cell, 3: Option Cell). And create a controller and manage the cell with it like:

```
       -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      if(indexpath.row== 0)
      {
          HeaderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.name = "foo";
          ....
      }
      else if(indexpath.row ==1 || indexpath.row ==3)
      {
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"blankCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
          [cell  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];

      }else{
           ....
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like above is a header view, and below a table view.

If the above part scrolls off it is the table view's `tableHeaderView`. In this case you can use a `UITableViewController`.

Otherwise you will have to use a `UIViewController` with a `UIView` as the header and a `UITableView` below it, and you have to declare the table view `delegate` and `datasource` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved same UI with help of bringing `UITableView` and add `UIView` with blue background as `tableHeaderView` like as below.

```
UIView *headerView =  [[UIView alloc] init...];
tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```